# Implementation Issue with JQuery DynamicDrive Menu

Tags: jquery, css

I am attempting to get the **MegaMenu Example 1** implemented in my JSFiddle:

http://dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddmegamenu.htm

The mousever is working, however, the the MegaPanel bottom fly-out doesnt function:

http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/MKMgu/

Does someone recognize the problem with this?

I'm no expert, but perhaps the problem could be with the JavaScript?

```
ddmegamenu.docinit({
    menuid:'solidmenu',
    dur:200 
})
```

I know that the MegaPanel does exist when I change the visibility here:

```
<div id="jkmenu" class="mega solidblocktheme">

.mega{
    width:300px;       
    padding:10px;
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    border:2px solid black;
    border-top-width:1px;
    background:white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #c8c8c8;    
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #c8c8c8;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #c8c8c8;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the markup structure. You can do this type of menu with just css and using nested lists `<ul><li>Parent<ul><li>Child</li></ul></li></ul>`

Comment: @elclanrs I realize this however there must be a reason that the MegaPanel isn't functioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the code was not being called correctly ... you were getting error

`Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function`

Changing the code in the JavaScript window to be run as part of the `<head>` fixes the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/MKMgu/19/